# Get selected items from a table with growing threshold SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm wondering if there is a way to get all the total number of selecteditems of a table with properties `growing` and `growingThreshold` set. It seems like the call
`oTable.getSelectedItems().length` only works for items in the table that are on display/visible.

[JSBIN Sample](https://jsbin.com/quyude/2/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

`getGrowingInfo().total` will return all items no matter visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

When `growing` property is set only visible items are being selected on clicking selectall.So it will return only visible items length.You may have to try for getting all items

```
ocheckSerialBatchJsonModel.getProperty("/results").length
```

If you want to get selected items you may have to add a seperate column for checkboxes and bind a property to enabled property of checkbox to json model first.Then you have to loop the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with sap.m.List. What I did was using the returned Listbase from the bindItems function and used the paths from getSelectedContextPaths(). Compared it with the oData and got all selected items. A little bit of a hack. Feel free to suggest something else. Didn't find anything else yet.